# How to DumpSave all variables or the whole notebook?

Tags: save

Is there a way to `DumpSave` all the variables in the notebook? Or better whole notebook so that opening it would restore all the definitions.

Comment: If you give the notebook its own context, it is then easy to save all definitions in that context using `DumpSave`.

Comment: How do I do it?

Comment: http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/NotebookDefaultContext.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition of a variable in a context is done by
`` myContext`a=100; ``
!! Typing "a" later will not give 100!! To call the content defined above you need to specifiy the context other wise it is assumed `` Global` ``. So use `` myContext`a `` to get 100.

Do this with all the needed variables in the notebook.
You can use `` DumpSave["file","myContext`"] `` to save all the definitions at once.

Comment: Does that mean that in principle all the global variables can be saved by `DumpSave["file","Global`"]`?

Comment: I was not sure if Global` context is far more than your defined variables. I just tried ?Global`* and indeed I only get my defined variables/functions and not some genereal Mathematica definitions.